# Azure Table Storage error: PropertyValueTooLarge

Tags: azure-table-storage

The documentation says that the combined size of the all properties on an entity must be less than 1MB.  I have a property which is a string that has .Length of 128410 and it is giving me this error.  Can anyone help?  I was expecting to be able to store up to 1 MB.

Comment: It seems I get this error if my property is more than 32768 long.  If I do 32769 then it will fail.

Comment: Per the doc's - A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to 64 KB in size. So a 32K string UTF-16 encoded is the 64K limit.

Answer (score 3):

A String value may be up to 64 KB in size. For more information about Azure Storage Tables, take a look at [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx)

Comment: Also if your value is not XML encoded it will be Base64'd so really 48K is the max for normal string values (including JSON in my case)